# Como executar formula quando a célular estiver preenchida?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Quero que a formula HOJE para de rodar quando preencher ou colar informação na célula A4 que faz parte dos dados.

```
=SE(A3="";"";HOJE()-A3)
```

Comment: Não entendi como está organizada sua planilha nem o significado de ".. formulá HOJE para de rodar... " mas você pode verificar se a célula A4 não está preenchida com: `ÉCÉL.VAZIA(A4)`.

Answer (score 0):

Basta usar o `SE()` dentro do `=SE()` novamente, algo como:

```
=SE(A3="";"";SE(A4="";"";HOJE()-A3))
```

Se entendi a lógica é para aplicar a fórmula somente se A3 e A4 estiverem preenchido.

Você também pode simplificar usando o `OU()`, assim:

```
=SE(OU(A3="";A4="");"";HOJE()-A3)
```

Dessa forma se A3 ou A4 forem vazios então não executa a formula, ao preencher ambos a formula será executada

Pode também fazer ao contrário, usar o `E()`, então a ordem dos argumentos mudará, exemplo:

```
=SE(E(A3<>"";A4<>"");HOJE()-A3;"")
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @SairoCoelho resolveu o problema? Se sim marque a resposta como correto, caso contrário comente qual foi o resultado. Se não souber como leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635